# How to perform a conditional sum in pyarrow

Tags: pyarrow

I'm trying to map a SQL query over to pyarrow and it's my first time tinkering with pyarrow.  I can't find a compute function that seems to fit the bill.

```
select
  group_col_1,
  group_col_2,
  sum(
    case
      when condition_col_1 = 'abc' then agg_column_value
      else null
    end
  ) as conditional_agg_col
from my_table
where filter_1 = 42
  and filter_2 ='meaning'
group by 1, 2
```

So far I have used the following, but would like to switch to a conditional sum based on the value in `condition_col_1`

```
table = pq.read_table(
  f"s3://cfsnowflakestage-dev/unload/quack/partitionedagain{partitions}",
  partitioning="hive",
  # filesystem=fs,
  filters=filters,
).select(["group_col_1", "group_col_2", "agg_column_value"])

# aggregate the table -- ¡¡This needs to be dynamic!!
grouped_table = pa.TableGroupBy(
  table, ["group_col_1", "group_col_2"]
).aggregate([("agg_column_value", "sum")])
```

I'll be creating a new column for this aggregation and more or less pivoting the row values to column aggregations.  It wouldn't hurt to show that, but I'm certain I can figure it out if there's a way to do the conditional sum.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrow does not support custom aggregate functions [yet](https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/33457). But the column can be projected before grouping.

```py
In []: table = pa.table({'condition_col_1': ['', 'abc'], 'agg_column_value': [1, 2]})

In []: new_column = pc.if_else(pc.equal(table['condition_col_1'], 'abc'), table['agg_column_value'], None)

In []: table.append_column('new_column_value', new_column)
Out[]: 
pyarrow.Table
condition_col_1: string
agg_column_value: int64
new_column_value: int64
----
condition_col_1: [["","abc"]]
agg_column_value: [[1,2]]
new_column_value: [[null,2]]
```

Comment: I'll give this a try as soon as I'm back into work.

Comment: This worked great!